# if...else statement will only print my if line

Tags: java, if-statement

I've run into a problem with my multi branch if...else statements. In the challenge question they ask us to print out a line if certain variables are true|false. My statements will only print my if statement, however they compile. I feel I'm either missing something in my if statement that allows it to continue if a statement is not true|false.

Here is what I have:

```
if ( isBalloon && isRed ) {
     isBalloon=false;
     isRed=false;
System.out.println("Not a balloon");
}
else if ( isBalloon && isRed ) {
    isBalloon=true;
    isRed=false;
System.out.println("Balloon");
}
```

Also, for clarity; when we do a multi branch statement (else if) requires variable declaration, where as (else) is just anything that makes our if statement false. Is this correct?

Comment: You have the same test condition in both branches. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: You basically ask: is the balon red twice, elseif only gets called if the first one is not valid

Comment: Thank you both! I also discovered after hours of frustration, but unwilling to copy paste from internet, that my code was also missing the ! symbol for creating a (if && !). Although I want to throw my computer sometimes, I'm really enjoying Java.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is easiest explained by pointing out that 'else if' in java isn't a separate keyword. So it is equivalent to the following (which is harder to read but points out why your code is executed only once)

```
if ( isBalloon && isRed ) {
    isBalloon=false;
    isRed=false;
    System.out.println("Not a balloon");
} else {
    if ( isBalloon && isRed ) {
        isBalloon=true;
        isRed=false;
        System.out.println("Balloon");
    }
}
```

this is what else if really does. When your code runs it hits the first if condition and when it is correct it will run the associated block. it then doesn't process the else block. (that is the idea: only if or else runs, not both).

It looks like if / else if / else if / else   has multiple blocks on the same level but secretly they are nested.

for instance

```
if (a) {
    // case a
} else if (b) {
    // case b
} else if (c) {
    // case c
} else {
    // otherwise:
}
```

is actually:

```
if (a) {
    // case a
} else {
    if (b) {
        // case b
    } else {
        if (c) {
            // case c
        } else {
            // otherwise
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you SO much. I'm very new to programming and my teacher reminds me that we are still trying to switch our brains over to think like a programmer and I'm just barely starting to see it happening. I appreciate the way you explained it to me.

Comment: No worries. there is a bit more that could be useful to say about it but I didn't want to overload / give too much information. If you're interested I can edit the answer and extend it a little bit more.

it is very much like switching your brain. see it as reading code like the compiler reads it. (because that is how the cpu will read it). 

Often we imagine code will work some way (how we want it to). Learning to read code how it will actually run is a skill that takes time